# Subir un cambio a todas las ramas

Tags: git

Tengo un repositorio, y todos los ramales (branches) tienen el mismo archivo común.

Quiero modificar el archivo en el branch master y que al darle `git push`, quiero que se suba dicha modificación en todos los ramales.

He intentado `git push --all origin` y no funciona.

He intentado `git config --add remote.origin.push 'refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*'` para que cuando haga push a origin remoto, igual, pero nada. (como recomiendan aquí: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1914579/set-up-git-to-pull-and-push-all-branches)

Pero no funciona, tampoco.

¿Alguna indicación sobre cómo subir a todos los ramales simultáneamente?

Answer (score 1):

La operación no la puedes realizar directamente en un solo comando, ya que eso implica mergear cada rama con la rama master. Lo que puedes hacer es ir situándote en cada rama, mergeandola con la **master** y luego subirlas al repo remoto todas en un solo comando.

Te voy a poner un breve ejemplo.
Partiendo de un repo de prueba llamado "prueba", en el dispongo de 4 ramas: **master**, **rama1**, **rama2** y **rama3**.

He hecho cambios en la rama master que en las ramas **rama1**, **rama2** y **rama3** no están.
Lo que hago es ir situandome en cada rama, y mergear los cambios.

```
$ git checkout rama1
Switched to branch 'rama1'

$ git merge master
Updating 59dc868..7f14f95
Fast-forward
 fichero.txt | 1 +
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)

$ git checkout rama2
Switched to branch 'rama2'

$ git merge master
Updating 59dc868..7f14f95
Fast-forward
 fichero.txt | 1 +
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)

$ git checkout rama3
Switched to branch 'rama3'

$ git merge master
Updating 59dc868..7f14f95
Fast-forward
 fichero.txt | 1 +
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
```

En este punto, todas las ramas del repo local tienen los cambios de la rama **master**. Ahora si que puedo subir al repo remoto todos los cambios en un solo comando:

```
$ git push origin --all
Password for 'https://--------@bitbucket.org': 
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To https://bitbucket.org/--------/pruebas.git
   59dc868..7f14f95  rama1 -> rama1
   59dc868..7f14f95  rama2 -> rama2
   59dc868..7f14f95  rama3 -> rama3
```

*Resumiendo, lo que deseas es que se suban los cambios de una rama en el resto de ramas del repo. Para eso, en el repositorio local, todas las ramas del repo, tienen que tener dichos cambios.*

Una vez que cada rama del repo tenga esos cambios (haciendo todos los merges con la rama que tiene los cambios) se pueden subir todas a la vez. Si tienes 20 ramas el proceso de hacer el merge en cada una de ellas puede ser un poco repetitivo. Para ello puedes ayudarte haciendo scripts para la automatización de los merges, es decir, escribir un script con los comandos de mergeado de cada rama una sola vez, y luego solo ejecutar ese script cada vez que quieras hacer un merge de todas las ramas. De esta manera no tendrás que ir rama por rama haciendo los merges siempre que quieras mezclar los cambios, solo será ejecutar el script que lo mezcle todo, y luego el push.

Answer (score 0):

En estricta teoria eso no se deberia hacer, se supone que tu tienes un equipo de trabajo y cada persona de tu equipo esta trabajando en una rama diferente correspondiente al fix que estan solucionando.

Por lo cual lo correcto es que tu subas el cambio a la rama de DEV, que es la rama de la cual todos los desarrolladores tuvieron que generar su rama donde estan trabajando, una vez que tu subas tu cambio a DEV, ya todos los demas desarrolladores tienen que bajar los cambios GIT PULL, igual en estricta teoria cuando un DEV inicia el día baja los cambios, al igual antes de enviar el PULL REQUEST tendria que bajar los cambios, para verificar que no hay conflictos antes de mandar su PULL REQUEST.

Bueno si no lo hicieron de todos modos a la hora de querer integrar te mandara un mensaje que existen CONFLICTOS y lo tendra que arreglar, saludos!